# Script to change logonworkstation in AD when running against multiple users

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, active-directory, windows-server-2012

We are currently experiencing issues with selective user accounts switching from All Computers, to The Following Computers under Logon Workstations in Active Directory.

I'd like to have a way to have a spreadsheet (CSV) that contains usernames, and then run the PowerShell script would read these values and set each user to All Computers under Logon Workstation.

Now, here is a simple script that works perfectly fine - Only thing is that you would have to enter each username manually each time you run this command:

```
"Set-AdUser -Identity User.Name -LogOnWorkstations $null"
```

Here is what I thought would work - But ends up not being the case:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\users.csv
Set-AdUser -Identity $csv -LogOnWorkstations $null
```

If anyone has an idea why my second script isn't working, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the seconds script shall I assume that `$csv` contains a list of users? If so `Set-AdUser` does not accept multiple `-Identity`'s. You would need to use a loop is the simplest answer.

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\users.csv
$csv | ForEach-Object{
   Set-AdUser -Identity $_ -LogOnWorkstations $null
}
```

This is *very* dependent on the structure of your CSV. If it has a column for `username` then you would need to update the cmdlet call.

```
Set-AdUser -Identity $_.UserName -LogOnWorkstations $null
```

If the file is just a list of users then don't even bother with `Import-CSV`

```
Get-Content C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\users.csv | ForEach-Object{
   Set-AdUser -Identity $_ -LogOnWorkstations $null
}
```